# Inserting data into a MySQL table with PHP when the values being inserted do not match the number of columns in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with over 100 columns, but I've shortened it to 6 for this example:

```
col0(autoincrement), col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
```

I'm getting data from external sources ($csvcontent below), and that data will have 6 or less values per line.  I'd like to use PHP to read these values into an array, and insert the array values into into my mysql table.

```
$csvcontent = file from external source
$fieldseparator = ",";
$lineseparator = "\n";
$linearray = array();

foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {
    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);
    $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);
    $query = "insert into MYTABLE values('','$linemysql');";
}
```

How can I insert the following rows, assuming that I don't know ahead of time how many values are stored inside of $csvcontent?  This existing code works well when I always have 6 values, but not when I have fewer.

```
insert into MYTABLE values('','1','2','3','4','5','6');  //works

insert into MYTABLE values('','1','2','3','4');          //doesn't work

insert into MYTABLE values('','1','2','3','4','5');      //doesn't work
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO mytable SET col1=1, col2=2...`

Comment: You should be using prepared statements though; very simple to prepare and execute queries like this using PDO.

Comment: Mention columns you want to insert into. Like `insert into MYTABLE(column1,column2) values('1','2')`

Comment: @vivek_23 My problem is that I don't know ahead of time how many columns there will be.  I could count the number if items in $linearray and try to display that number of columns, but I was hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: @all above: They want to do this dynamically.

Comment: Or, alter the database column definition to have a default value.

Comment: You could pad the array to the same size using some default value, but please use prepared statements.

Comment: *My problem is that I don't know ahead of time how many columns there will be* ... is not an ideal database design or usage. One should never leave DDL and DML calls open-ended for application to manipulate schema or data on the fly. Relational DBs are planned systems and queries should be explicit regarding identifiers like tables and columns.

Comment: @miken32 - would just changing the column default value from "not null" to "null" fix this?  I'm going to give that a try

Comment: The default is to set a column to null, but this conflicts with `NOT NULL` so yes that would resolve it, or explicitly setting a default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on the size of `$linearray`, you can create a column sequence and attach that to your insert query.

```
<?php


$columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6'];

$linearray_samples =  [
            [1,2,3,4,5],
            [1,2,3],
            [1,2,3,4],
            [1],
            [1,2],
            [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        ];


foreach($linearray_samples as $each_sample){
    echo "(",commaSeparatedColumns($each_sample,$columns),")",PHP_EOL;
}

function commaSeparatedColumns($sample,$columns){
    return implode(",",array_slice($columns,0,count($sample)));
}
```

The code outputs:

```
(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
(col1,col2,col3)
(col1,col2,col3,col4)
(col1)
(col1,col2)
(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/QLnFo

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm currently playing around with it.